# Blazor component not updating after changing parameter

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Prefacing this with I'm fairly new to Blazor, so I may be missing part of the lifecycle here.

In my Blazor application, I have a page that also has a shared component to generate a nav menu. The nav menu changes based upon a parameter passed to the page, but when clicking any of the links, the component does not update.

Page:

```
@page "/"
@page "/{department}"

<NavMenu Department="@Department" />

<div class="content">

</div>


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? Department { get; set; }
}
```

Nav Menu Component:

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="dropdown-container">
        <a href="/@Department">Home</a>
    </div>
    @foreach (LinkMenu menu in menus)
    {
        <div class="dropdown-container">
            <a>@menu.HeaderText</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
                @foreach (string[] link in menu.Links)
                {
                    <a href="@link[1]">@link[0]</a>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? Department { get; set; }

    public List<LinkMenu> menus = new List<LinkMenu>();
    
    //ignore this syntax, this is a bastardization from multiple testing iterations
    protected override async void OnInitialized()
    {
        GenerateNavLinks();
        StateHasChanged(); //does not update regardless of this
    }

    private void GenerateNavLinks()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            //test var, remove later
            LinkMenu linkMenu = new LinkMenu();
            linkMenu.HeaderText = string.Format("Header{0}", i);

            string[] link = { Department, string.Format("/{0}", Department) }; //update this to actual link generation after testing
            string[] otherLink = { "Go somewhere else", "/NewDepartment" };
            linkMenu.Links.Add(link);
            linkMenu.Links.Add(otherLink);
            menus.Add(linkMenu);
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried putting this into an `AppState` helper class that I injected so I could move the nav to `MainLayout` but that results in similar issues. The only place I can think of to update `Department` is overriding the `OnInitialized` of my page, but even then it doesn't change anything.

I'm assuming `OnInitialized` is not firing again because I'm technically not loading to a different page, just trying to update the changed DOM elements, but I'm not familiar enough to know how to force an update of the component.

Some example pictures:

Prior to clicking "Go somewhere else" link
[image: pre link]

After clicking "Go somewhere else" link
[image]

Comment: Why your `OnInitialized` has `async`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should be in `OnParametersSet`, which is called every time the parameters are set.

```
    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        GenerateNavLinks();
        // No state has changed is required
    }
```

Please note that this is totally wrong, and will get you into all sorts of trouble.

```cs
protected override async void OnInitialized()
```

If you have async code to run use `OnInitializedAsync` or `OnParametersSetAsync`.

Comment: NP (it looked a bit strange!).  If you want a bit of background reading on components, there's an article (of mine) on CodeProject - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5277618/A-Dive-into-Blazor-Components